# Backslash in string in Powershell

Tags: powershell, backslash

I have a powershell script where my server name is defined as: `<servername>name\abc</servername>`

Definition is made in xml file:

```
<environment>
    <cust>
        <servername>name\abc</servername>
        ...
    </cust>
</environment>
```

Then I need to call my servername in .ps1 as:

```
$servername = $envCust.servername
Write-Host "$servername"
```

Unfortunately, PS considers \ as token recognition error.

Executing script...

```
line 2:60 token recognition error at: '"name\a'
line 2:79 token recognition error at: '";\r'
line 2:60 token recognition error at: '"name\a'
line 2:79 token recognition error at: '";\r'
```

Script compilation errors:

Do you know how could I use \ in my script?

Comment: Try surrounding the property name in single quotes.  e.g.: `$envCust.'servername'`

Comment: Looks like you are storing the servicename in an XML file. Please [edit] into the question how you extract it. Powershell's escape is the backtick ` , not backslash (unless working on regexes, where backslash is escape as usual).

Comment: This works; is this similar to how you're creating `$envCust`?  `$envCust = ([xml]'<root><servername>name\abc</servername></root>').DocumentElement;$servername = $envCust.servername;write-host $servername`

Comment: please show how you opened and parsed the xml file

Comment: $envFile = [XML](Get-Content -Path ($environment + ".xml"))

Comment: Works for me.  `$xml = [xml](cat file.xml); $servername = $xml.environment.cust.servername`

Answer (score -1):

use a backquote " ` " to escape the backslash character, Windows allows both forward and backslash for filepaths, so using backslash for escaping characters would not work.

Use speech marks on each end of the string for variable expansion, or for this string to be literal, then use a single quote on each side of the string.

Comment: backslash is just a normal character in powershell. No need to escape it